# Ember-data: validation errors on relationships (hasMany)

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, has-many, validationerror

I'm trying to create record with associated records in one request. In case if some of nested records have validation errors, I'd like to access appropriate errors on that record. I'm using json-api adaptor, so what should be the format of errors from the backend? I'm trying something like this, with no luck though:

```
{"errors":[
  {
    "detail": "can't be blank",
    "source": {
      "pointer":"data/relationships/steps/0/data/attributes/est_threshold"
    }
  }
]}
```

According to this line, it should be implemented somehow:
https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/addon/adapters/errors.js#L7

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to sideload nested records in the data.  The example structure given in the ember guides is:

```
{
  "post": {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Node is not omakase",
    "comments": [1, 2, 3]
  },

  "comments": [{
    "id": 1,
    "body": "But is it _lightweight_ omakase?"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "body": "I for one welcome our new omakase overlords"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "body": "Put me on the fast track to a delicious dinner"
  }]
}
```

https://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/models/the-rest-adapter/

Comment: The question was about validation errors, not loading the data. And I use json-api adapter, as explicitly said in the question.

Comment: Oh, apologies, I should have read it more carefully.  Could it be that the JSON you posted is invalid?  Looks like there's a close square bracket missing.

Comment: Oh, it's the issue of formatting. When I posted it was in one line, so I reformatted it for readability. So it comes from server with a square bracket.

Answer (score 0):

So it doesn't seem to be implemented yet. I found kinda hackish way to do that in the model mixin:

```
`import Ember from 'ember'`

RelatedErrors = Ember.Mixin.create

  save: ->
    @_super().catch (resp) =>
      resp.errors.forEach (err) =>
        if [_, rel, idx, attr] = err.source.pointer.match /^data\/relationships\/(\w+)\/(\d+)\/data\/attributes\/(\w+)$/
          @get(rel).objectAt(idx).get('errors').add(attr, err.detail)

`export default RelatedErrors`
```

However, `add` on DS.Errors is deprecated, so this is still not a perfect solution. Also invalid state of related models need to be cleared before each commit, which is not happening this far.